# Custom Control Component failed to use up('target') navigation

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

We have written a custom control component (basically a `Ext.form.FieldContainer` which supply navigation buttons based on components he is a subchild of.)

As a example let us say it is a tabpanel and we want to add navigation buttons to jump to the next or previous tab and lets say we name our new components xtype `navcontrol`

We may have something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            // our new component. It should create one Button
            dockedItems: [{xtype:'navcontrol'}] 
        }]
    },{
        xtype: 'container',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            // again our new component. It should create two Buttons
            dockedItems: [{xtype:'navcontrol'}] 
        }]
    },{
        xtype: 'container',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            // and again our new component. It should create one Button
            dockedItems: [{xtype:'navcontrol'}] 
        }]
    }]
}
```

Please do not tell me that this is overnesting and I can spare the containers; I just want to show that the `navcontrol` component is nested deeper.

What the `navcontrol` class needs to do is to acquire all necessary information from the next `tabpanel` up in the hierarchy. So our first try was to do this within the `initComponent`, cause we want to initialize our component. We added the appropriate code after the `callParent` call but no luck, `this.up('tabpanel')` returned `null`.

It seems like the Component didn't know his parent... My first thought: stupid

So based on the API we found `onAdded` which has the parent as argument and seems to set it. OK, this can makes sense. We prepare with `initComponent` and set related thing up with `onAdded`. We moved the code from the `initComponent` to the `onAdded`, again after the `callParent` call. And again it returned `null`!

So at which point (before rendering) are we able to query the hierarchy (without subscribing to a event the fire our self)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because initialization happens in this order:

1. Container gets instantiated
2. Container creates instances of child components/containers
3. Container adds component/container to itself

So say you have A -> B -> C. By the time `onAdded` is called for `C`, it gets added to `B`, but `B` isn't yet added to `A`.

`beforeRender` would be a template method you could override where the container hierarchy will be setup.

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply. Yeah ,this would work. The only point is, that this method is marked as private. So either the documentation is wrong or I am not supposed to override it. I just want to prevent broken code when updating the framework. So do you think I can rely on it when overriding (based on OOP private cannot be overridden)?

Comment: Yes, you should be pretty safe to override it, it's used fairly extensively throughout the framework. It should probably be promoted to protected.

Comment: Thanks again! We will go with it.